# How can I create dynamic form select in Rails 6 with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and web development. I am trying to create a dynamic form select on my category and subcategory form such that subcategories associated with a selected category will be automatically loaded. Here is is what I have tried but did not work. Whenever I reload the page I page empty drop downlist the subcategories even if I selected an item

ROUTE:

```
post '/subcategories/find_by_category', to: 'subcategories#find_by_category'
```

CONTROLLER

```rb
class SubcategoriesController < ApplicationController

  def show; end

  def find_by_category
    category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    subcategories = category.subcategories.find_all
    render json: {subcategories: subcategories}
  end
end
```

MODEL

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories
end

class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :category, required: false
end
```

VIEW

```
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Category</label>
           <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>  
          </div>

            <div class="field">
                   <label class="label">Sub Category</label>
                   <%= f.select :subcategory_id, options_for_select([])  %>  
             </div>



               <script>

                 $(document).ready(function(){
                 var getSubcategories = function(category_id){
                 var subcategories = $('#service_subcategory_id');
                 $($subcategories).empty();

                $.service('/subcategories/find_by_category', { category_id: category_id},  
                function(data){
                $.each(data.subcategories, function(index, subcategory){
                var option = $('<option />');
                option.attr('value', subcategory.id);
                option.text(subcategory.name);
                option.appendTo($subcategories);

                 });

                   })

                    };

              var getSelectedCategory = function(){
                return $('#service_category_id').val();

              };

               $('#service_category_id').change(function() {
             var category_id = getSelectedCategory();
           getSubcategories (category_id);

            });

           getSubcategories(getSelectedCategory());


             });

          </script>
```

I get this error on the console

```
readyException.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: $subcategories is not defined
at getSubcategories (edit:493)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (edit:520)
at mightThrow (deferred.js:97)
at process (deferred.js:139)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a different variable than what you have defined.

You wrote:

```
var subcategories = $('#service_subcategory_id');
$($subcategories).empty();
```

There are two issues here.

1. You did not define the variable `$subcategories`, but you are attempting to reference it.
2. You are attempting to wrap the `$subcategories` variable in JQuery, which I *think* would be redundant with what you are trying to do, as the variable above is already a JQuery object.

You can name the variable starting with `$` if that helps you remember it is a JQuery object, but this should get you to the next blocker:

```
var $subcategories = $('#service_subcategory_id');
$subcategories.empty();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I have tried your recommendation another error is what i get on the console:readyException.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: $.service is not a function
    at getSubcategories (edit:498)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (edit:522)
    at mightThrow (deferred.js:97)
    at process (deferred.js:139)

Comment: @GeniClasses that's good news, it means your code is now executing to the next line. I don't see `service` as a JQuery method, though. https://api.jquery.com/, so it looks like you're trying to call a method that doesn't exist, unless you're using a JQuery extension?

Comment: @GeniClasses I've changed your tags. You're having Javascript issues, unrelated to Rails or Ruby. Hopefully the JS and JQuery tags will help you get some more help.